# The better way to ask for input?

Tags: java

I am wondering which is the best way to go with java code. I need to create a class with simple prompts for input.. I have tried using both classes and cannot work out the particular benefits for each. Is this because I am still in the early stages of programming or are there situations that will occur as it becomes more complex??

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class myClass
{
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    public String getInput(String prompt)  
    {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        return stdin.nextLine();
    }

}
```

... or

```
import java.io.*;

public class myClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Input something: ");
        String name = stdin.readLine();
    }
}
```

I know these examples are showing different methods within these classes, but thought this might serve well for the discussion.

*I'm really not sure which site is the best to ask this on.*

Comment: This must be an academic exercise.  In the real world, no one ever writes code like this, and no one has for about 30 years.  Either we build a UI, or get the input from the command line arguments, or read a file.  It pains me that schools are still forcing students to deal with the difficulties of console IO

Comment: @kevincline yes it is a uni assignment.. but what am I supposed to do?.. *shrugs* I totally agree. the most fun I ever had writing code was when someone asked me to read and write to a serial port in vb.net..

Comment: To be fair, though, it isn't any worse than teaching them about arrays by having them build a contact management system that saves everything to a pre-allocated 100-member array.

Comment: @CharlieKilian, I did that kind of assignements...working with arrays to store/edit products. I am just curious, what you think would be a better way to introduce a beginner student to arrays?

Comment: @joe Arrays are tricky, because in modern languages like C# and Java, in practice they end up being used more often than not like a poor man's `List<>`. They are kind of a hold-over from C/C++, where a big appeal of an array was that it stored the values sequentially in memory. That usually doesn't matter when you have a CLR or JRE executing your code.

Comment: Obviously I'm making some pretty sweeping generalizations due to the short format here. I think I'd be tempted to teach a more modern data structure before an array, but I'm not 100% sure about that. The class libraries use both, and the difference can be confusing to beginners. Clearly I'm no teacher.

Comment: But I remember being frustrated in those classes that students were getting the idea that they might use an array to manage a set of records, when a real program would never do that.

Comment: The best way is to do it politely.

Comment: @CharlieKilian, thanks for taking time to explain, i totally agree with you on that fact, and i personally believe that learning how things work is more important than just memorizing how to use them (e.g. creating a linked list structure rather than using it from the library), again for learning purposes!! but the real world is a whole different story...unfortunately :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been a Java programmer for 6 years now, and I rarely have to worry about how to read input from the command line.  Most times, when I'm dealing with input and output, they are usually streams of some sort and therefore using a `BufferedReader` is generally a best practice, since it takes the bottleneck off having to read a file line by line.

However, for what you're out to do, using `System.in` with `Scanner` is perfectly fine.  Lets just say that if I wanted to handle large amounts of input, perhaps I would wrap `System.in` with a `BufferedInputStream` for efficiency, but if your program is waiting on *you*, then there is no advantage gained.

Comment: ty you have cleared up for me what I was wondering. I have noticed some people favor the Scanner class, but my previous experiences of reading and writing in vb.net, have made me think otherwise cheers

Comment: @Skippy The usage of Scanner is independent from the need to buffer your input.  Scanner simply helps you tokenize the input, and that may be useful even when you're having to deal with large inputs.  But yeah, if you don't care what *types* you're reading in (aka, you want to copy a file), Scanner is excessive.

Comment: Oh I wasn't referring to buffering per se, just the general ease of streamReader, read write options.. if that makes sense? (I'm only beginner, so never sure of the correct term to use)

Comment: @Skippy Ah ok.  :)  My advice to you would be to, whenever confronted with two or more classes which derive from the same class (i.e. InputStream, List, etc.), try to understand the differences and hence what would be better suited for you.

Comment: Ah good advice.. I am so familiar with vb.net, have just done a term of python.. and what with wed programming and databses, I become a bit of a jumbled mess. I know this will ease up with time.. thnx for your help.. I plan to become a programmer, so hopefully, will be here again :)

Comment: @Skippy I'm happy to help.  Hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 2):

Simply reading System.in with BufferedReader, you end up writing a few lines of boilerplate code.

Moving up to Scanner, as suggested in Neil's answer, makes it easier to pull data of various types out of the stream.

Personally, when a command-line interface is really the best choice (which includes any time it's a stated requirement), I like to use [System.console()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/io/Console.html). It's not always available (for example, when running inside some IDEs), but when it is, it offers useful things like readPassword() which prevents the user's input from being echoed back to the screen, and it makes it so that you can read from and write to the console using the same object.  It's really designed around the typical use case for command line tools that require user interaction.

Using System.console() doesn't explicitly conflict with Scanner:

```
Console console = System.console();
String name = console.readLine("Please enter your name: ");
Scanner ageScanner = new Scanner(console.readLine("How old are you? ");
int age = ageScanner.nextInt();
```

They don't quite play perfectly together in this way, since you have to instantiate a new Scanner for each line.  Console does offer access to a Reader, which you can use to instantiate a Scanner:

```
Console console = System.console();
String name = console.readLine("Please enter your name: ");
Scanner consoleScanner = new Scanner(console.reader());
int age = consoleScanner.nextInt();
```

(Disclaimer: I haven't tried the above code, and I'm not exactly sure how things will behave if you use console.readLine() intermixed with usages of a Scanner made from console.reader().  For clarity and consistency, it might be wise to choose one method and stick to it.)

Sticking with this example, I'd be more likely to write:

```
Console console = System.console();
String name = console.readLine("Please enter your name: ");
int age = Integer.parseInt(console.readLine("How old are you? ");
```

Depending on your needs, you may find that one, the other, or both are best suited to your needs. Generally, I find that Scanner is better suited to reading a file with a known format, and Console is better suited to interactive user input, because Scanner really shines when you have multiple tokens per line of input.  Asking a user to enter that sort of input interactively is probably not going to result in the best experience.

JavaDoc: [java.io.Console](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/io/Console.html)

Related question: [Java: How to get input from System.console()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4644415/439793)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I've significantly expanded on my answer.  Apologies; I wrote the first answer on my phone.  :)